# java.lang.Exception: Torrc config did not verify

Tags: help, orbot, android

Orbot is starting…
Orbot is starting…
I've installed Tor in my Asus but i cant used because it appears this message:

```
updating settings in Tor service
updating torrc custom configuration...
success.
Orbot is starting…
Tor (1): sh: <stdin>[2]: /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/tor: not executable: magic 7F45
Unable to start Tor: java.lang.Exception: Torrc config did not verify
Set background service to FOREGROUND
Orbot is deactivated*
```

What can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you modify your torr config file or muck with any of the files in the /data/data/org.torproject.android folder? It's unlikely that the normal orbot wouldn't remember to make the tor binary executable. Remove the app and reinstall.

Comment: Have the same problem as he said any options to fix ?